# OnClick по вложенному RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, recyclerviewadapter

Суть очень проста. есть список `RecyclerView` в элементах которого есть еще свои `RecyclerView` . проблема в том, что при клике на главный итем, а точнее по его месту где отрисовывается вложенный `RecyclerView` то клик не детектится.

Как можно исправить это? Второй список нужен только в качестве отображения, клика на нем нет.

Comment: Попробуйте корневым элементом главного `RecyclerItem` сделать `FrameLayout` и положить в него второй `Recycler` с атрибутом `clickable=false`. А клики ловить по корневому фрэйму

Comment: Не выходит, по всякому пробовал...

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос дилетантский, сам дам на него ответ спустя 4 года. Не нужно вешать слушатели на родительские элементы, если хотите слушать дочерние.

Я цеплял onClick по сути на весь дочерний Recycler, чего делать не нужно было